# Targeting SVG icons from defs file with CSS not working in Webkit

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm working on a project that uses some SVG icons that I'd like to be able to style with css for different scenarios and hover states, but what I have just doesn't seem to work in Webkit, though it's working as expected in Firefox:

http://codepen.io/poopsplat/pen/ycaod

I'm using these SVGs in the way that Chris Choyier outlines in his Icon System with SVG Sprites article, which is by including a defs file on the page and then placing `<svg>` elements on the page that reference specific `<symbol>` elements by `id` using the `<use>` tag. I'm also utilizing Grunt-svgstore to automate the build of the SVG defs file.

Chris's example (http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/EBHlD) works great in Webkit, even if you begin to nest the icons into containers and target them that way, so that's not the issue. In that particular example Chris uses `<g>` elements and targets those, while the automated output file form Grunt-svgstore wraps the individual icons in `<symbol>` elements with `id`s that are referenced in the HTML, but I tried formatting my SVG defs file in that way to test if that was the issue, and it's not.

I'm at a loss for what is different about my working example and something like Chris's example — anyone have any ideas as to why targeting these SVG icons is failing in Webkit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SVG icons have presentation attributes (like "fill", "stroke"...), thus these styles defined by css for use element are ignored.
So, you should remove all presentation attributes.
I made simple sample. http://jsfiddle.net/n3n2vLk8/

svg(html)

```
<svg style="display:none">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="withFill" viewBox="-5 -5 10 10">
            <circle r="5" fill="orange"/><!--You can't override this value-->
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="noFill" viewBox="-5 -5 10 10">
            <circle r="5"/>
        </symbol>
    </defs>
</svg>
<svg width="200px" height="100px">
    <use xlink:href="#withFill" width="100" height="100"/>
    <use xlink:href="#noFill" x="100" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>
```

css:

```
use{
    fill: red;
}
```

Comment: Yep — exactly it. Thank you! I realized this before I saw your answer and took care of it already. I was saving the SVG icons using Illustrator, which I realized saved them with the presentational markup causing the problem. Since I am using Grunt.js to automate the concatenation and cleaning of my SVG files I opted to re-save each of my icons with no colors applied to the strokes or fills, and now I’m able to style them with CSS as expected.